# Use 2 urls for the same directory using htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

Is it possible to using htaccess?
I want to keep my original url "menu", but also use /en/menu/ for it.
Here is my code so far (sorry I am terrible at htaccess):

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /server/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/menu/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)en/menu/ [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ /menu/ [L,QSA]
```

Comment: You only need the alias module and its `Alias` directive for this. Check the documentation...

Comment: RewriteRule ^/outback/en/menu/$ /outback/menu/ [L]

Comment: I tried the code above but its not working ass well